# Textbook for quantitative biochemistry with thermodynamics, as an alternative to Voet, Voet & Pratt (Fundamentals of Biochemistry)?

Tags: biochemistry, theoretical-biology, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a great textbook on biochemistry that covers core topics: relevant aspects of thermodynamics, reaction kinetics, metabolism (e.g. krebs cycle, respiration, etc.). Ideally it would also be quantitative in its approach and use mathematical models where relevant.

The classic textbook is Voet & Voet & Pratt (Fundamentals of Biochemistry) and I think that's a horribly written textbook. It uses concepts before actually defining them (and when it does define them the definitions are obtuse and have no conceptual motivation). Is there an alternative to this? Any recommendations?

Comment: Stryer?? As far as I remember it had the most thermodynamics of all other books. [Example section](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22584/). You should add more details on what exactly you are looking for. What level of thermodynamics you want etc. See the tag wiki for [tag:book-recommendation]

Comment: I've always liked Lehninger Principles of Biochemistry. Seems like it would be a good book for you.

Comment: I would also vote for Stryer. But none of the biochem books do the technical stuff (kinetics, thermodynamics) properly I think. For this, get a copy of Atkins' Physical Chemistry.